# rails -v shows wrong version when using rvm

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rvm

I've just tried to update to Rails 3.1.3 using RVM with the following commands:

> rvm install ruby-1.9.3-p0
>
> rvm --default use ruby-1.9.3-p0

If I query the current version or ruby:

> ruby -v

I get the correct version: ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30 revision 33570) [x86_64-darwin10.8.0]

Then to update the gems:

> gem update --system

This gives me  version 1.8.24

I then create my gemset and set it as my default:

> rvm ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails313 --create --default

and finally install the Rails gem:

> gem install rails

When I query the version of rails:

> rails -v

I get Rails 3.0.11 ... my old version of Rails

If I try to start my Rails server

> rails s

I get a huge error:

> .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails313/gems/activesupport-3.0.11/lib/active_support dependencies.rb:239:in `require': dlopen(/Users/lss_dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails313/gems/ruby-debug-base19-0.11.25/lib/ruby_debug.bundle, 9): Symbol not found: _ruby_current_thread (LoadError)

With a lot of complaints about dependencies.

My gemfile.lock does contain the following block:

> rails (3.0.11)
>
> ```
>   actionmailer (= 3.0.11)
>
>   actionpack (= 3.0.11)
>
>   activerecord (= 3.0.11)
>
>   activeresource (= 3.0.11)
>
>   activesupport (= 3.0.11)
>
>   bundler (~> 1.0)
>
>   railties (= 3.0.11)
> ```

Does this have something to do with it or should I even be touching the gemfile.lock file??

I'm using rvm version 1.10.0, any help would be appreciated

Comment: Did you try to delete the gemfile lock and try again? also read this http://stjhimy.com/posts/10-five-quick-steps-to-set-up-rvm-with-rails-2-and-rails3

Comment: Did you run the comand 'bundle install'?

Comment: When I run 'bundle install' I get **Using rails (3.0.11)**  I've tried trashing my gemfile.lock too and ran 'gem install rails' but it still is showing me version 3.0.11

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To answer my own (extended) question...

Trashing the gemfile.lock file allowed me to just run

> bundle install

ensuring that I had my Rails gem set to the correct version (3.1.3), which worked.  The issue that I was running into then was when I started my rails server I got the following browser error

**undefined method `consider_all_requests_local' for ActionController::Base:Class**

Initially I thought this was due to some routing changes in Rails 3.1.*  As it turned out in my application_controller.rb file I was dealing with 404 errors and had the following block:

```
unless ActionController::Base.consider_all_requests_local
   rescue_from Exception, :with => :render_404
end
```

> ActionController::Base.consider_all_requests_local

Is now deprecated and substituting in:

> Rails.application.config.consider_all_requests_local

Did the trick.

Thank you for your help and I hope this helps someone in the future

Answer (score 0):

You may have to swap the version of rvm / ruby and then install.
This may be of use: https://rvm.io/gemsets/basics/

Comment: Ok, getting there! With everyones help I've trashed the gemset and my gemfile.lock file and just ran **bundle install** ensuring that I set the correct Rails version in my Gemfile. The rails server now runs and shows the correct version ... but now when I go the the browser I get: **undefined method `consider_all_requests_local' for ActionController::Base:Class**  Has routes changed in version 3.1.3, I'm upgrading from 3.0.11??